# remove specific values on a change jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js

**BACKGROUND**

I have 3 fields that hold certain Data. They all share common class name of polo-basket--labels.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-8">
        <label for="basket__label">basket  labels in the dog</label>
        <select class="fancy-dropdown" name="selected_basket__labels" id="polo-basket--labels" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Choose..." style="width: 400px">
            {{#each referencePanelbaskets}}
            <option {{#ifArrayContains ../polosWithoutUncertainString this}}selected{{/ifArrayContains}} value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="columns small-6">
        <label for="basket__labels_on_parent_a">Parent A/label>
        <select class="fancy-dropdown polo-parent-basket--labels" name="basket__labels_on_parent_a[]" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Choose..." style="width: 400px">
            {{#each referencePanelbaskets}}
            <option {{#ifArrayContains ../parentAsWithInsteadOfUncertain this}}selected{{/ifArrayContains}} value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="columns small-6">
        <label for="basket__labels_on_parent_b">Parent B</label>
        <select class="fancy-dropdown polo-parent-basket--labels" name="basket__labels_on_parent_b[]" multiple="true" data-placeholder="Choose..." style="width: 400px">
            {{#each referencePanelbaskets}}
            <option {{#ifArrayContains ../parentBsWithInsteadOfUncertain this}}selected{{/ifArrayContains}} value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </div>
```

Whenever i remove a value from the first div the one with

> class="fancy-dropdown"

it triggers the jquery posted below and nukes all the values in the field Parent A and Parent B. Parent and Parent B are the ones with

> class="fancy-dropdown polo-parent-basket--labels"

```
$('#polo-basket--labels').change(function () {
  var options = _.map($(this).val(), function (basket__label) {
    return {
      id: basket__label,
      text: basket__label
    }
  })
  $('.polo-parent-basket--labels').val(null).select2('destroy').empty().select2({data: options})
})
```

**Issue**

However i want to change this behavior. So anytime i remove value from the

> class="fancy-dropdown"

I only want to remove that value from the ParentA and ParentB div and not remove everything.

I am very new to jquery and also i never worked with .hbs so i would love any input.

**What did I try so far**

I figured that the last line in the Jquery function

> $('.polo-parent-basket--labels').val(null).select2('destroy').empty().select2({data:
>   options})

is the one causing the nuke of all values so i thought maybe i can pass in data here but with no luck.

Comment: By the way, IDs _must_ be unique. I'm not sure what "share common id" means for sure, but an ID doesn't ID anything if there are multiple. It's invalid HTML.

Comment: oops typo i meant they share same class name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use *DOM traversal* to be more specific in your selector, something like this:

```
  // go up to the nearest row element, then grab the next sibling row
  let parentA = $(this).closest('tr').next('tr');
  // ... and the one after that
  let parentB = parentA.next('tr');

  parentA.val(null).select2('destroy').empty().select2({data: options});
  parentB.val(null).select2('destroy').empty().select2({data: options});
})
```

There are ways to reduce code repetition, but this gives you an idea where to start.  You could simplify things dramatically by grouping the three related rows into a container, for example.

Comment: Hmm i think i get your part of not be repetitive.  Regarding my issue I am basically dealing with 3 boxes that all have values populated. When i remove a value from  <select class="fancy-dropdown"  i want to only remove that particular value from the  <select class="fancy-dropdown polo-parent-basket--labels"  classes but currently all values get removed from the  <select class="fancy-dropdown polo-parent-basket--labels"

Answer (score 0):

When you are in "change" fonction, add a class to the element .

```
$('#theElementYouWantToSelect).attr("class", "newClassName");
```

And after that you remove the element with that element.

```
$('.newClassName').remove();
```